# jQuery output field required (from validation) into a specified div

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello I'm stuck with jQuery validation, I basically need it so that when the form is validating when the submit button is click the "field required" message will output put into a specific `div`.

This is what I have tried but I know I am way off:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#bookingform").validate();
    $(".small").append(".error");

});
```

`.small` is the `div` tag i want the `"required field"` message to show in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what your looking for is `errorPlacement` this allows you to place the error message where you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bookingform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.prev().find('.small') );
        }
    });
});
```

`error` contains the error message, `element` is the form field with the error

Basically the code above is saying find the element with the error, find the prev element before it which is the `<label>` element, then use `find()` to find the `small` class div inside it and append the error to it.

Comment: WOW this is exactly what is was looking for!!!! can't thank you enough. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  Took a little to completely understand the question at first; I thought you had just one div you wanted to output the error/errors into, made more sense when I went to the URL you provided and looked at the source.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are checking is if the field is filled out then:

Wrap each row(label and input combo) in a span with the class requiredField. Then uses the following JS

```
function()
{
  var error = false;
  $('.requiredField').each(function()
  {
    if($.trim($(this).find('input').val()) === '')
    {
      $(this).find('.class').text('required field');
      error = true;
    }
  });
}
if(!error)
{
  $('#bookingform').submit();
}
```

If you are doing specific field validation change the class on the row wrapper to something like requiredDate/requiredPhone and put another `$('.requiredDate').each` with the specific validation for those fields.

Comment: What problems, exactly are you having?

Comment: Hi phizzle i found the code that i needed it was basicly this: errorElement: "div",
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $("#error_goes_here").html(error);
}
i needed the error code to display in the a div tag. but i have it working yay. thank oyu for your help tho really appreciate it :)